# What is the relation between energy levels of hydrogen atom in Bohr's solution to that of Dirac solution

Tags: atomic-physics, dirac-equation, hydrogen

In Dirac solution for hydrogen atom, the energy levels are calculated as positive

\begin{equation}
E=\frac{mc^{2}}{R(t)\sqrt{1+\frac{z^{2}\alpha^{2}}{\left(n+\sqrt{\left(j+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-z^{2}\alpha^{2}}\right)^{2}}}} 
\end{equation}

, while in Bohr's model the energy levels are negative

\begin{equation}  
E=\frac{-Ze^{2}}{8\pi\epsilon_{0}r} 
\end{equation}

How are these two related to each other?

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer wasn't obvious to me at first glance so it seems a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $E$ in your expression is the quantity calculated using the operator $i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, so it is the total energy. As $n \rightarrow \infty$ this energy $E$ goes to the rest energy of the electron $m_ec^2$ as we'd expect. For finite $n$ the energy is lower than $m_ec^2$ with the difference being the binding energy of the electron.

To compare the Dirac $E$ with the Bohr energies just subtract off $m_ec^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_quantum_theory)

Energy in Dirac model $E_d$ is related to energy in Bohr's model $E_b$ as

$E_b \approx E_d - m_ec^2$

where $m_e$ is mass of electron and $c$ is speed of light. The answer above is not useful.

Comment: Exactly in what paragraph in the link you find this relation?

Comment: Just look for sub heading Energy levels. Anyway John has also confirmed above the same thing.